# PIL error: The _imaging C module is not installed

Tags: python, module, python-imaging-library

I have PIL (Python imaging library) installed.

When I run Python:

```
import PIL
import Image
import _imaging
```

I don't get errors. However, when running my app, it raises

```
The _imaging C module not installed
```

Comment: I had the same problem.  Clean install of **PIL 1.1.7** (currently latest) on top of clean install on **python 2.7.8** (currently latest) fixed the problem.  Make sure your python 2.7 is **32-bit**.

Answer (score 3):

I posted this response on the link that you sent (thank you for that), but figured I'd post on source as well.  Sorry for the dupe post.

I was hoping that there was a way to do this without recompiling stuff. I happen to be using virtualenv. I did find that if I blew away my virtual env install and then reinstall with pip, the Imaging started to work again. These steps seemed to work (note, I’m using OSX)

Not sure if this mattered, but checking to see if jpeg is installed

```
winesap:~ $ port installed | grep -i jpeg
  jpeg @7_0
  jpeg @8a_0 (active)
```

Make sure I have PIP installed

```
sudo port -v install py26-pip
```

Remove the old virtual environment I had and recreate it

```
rm -rf ve
virtualenv –no-site-packages –distribute ve
. ./ve/bin/activate
```

Install pil and django into the virtualenv

```
echo “pil” > requirements.pip
echo “django” >> requirements.pip
pip-2.6 install -E ./ve/ -r requirements.pip
```

Test to see if the import works now.  Note lack of obnoxious C module error

```
python
>>import import ImageFont 
>>
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Yeah no problem, mine was solely based on just pure apache mod_wsgi django and python

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, remove _imaging.pyd and _imagingft.pyd inside C:\Python27.
Leave all _imaging modules inside the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL folder.

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some things that might help you if `from PIL import Image` works but `import _imaging` fails. If `Image` fails too, see the *Note* at the end.

On Ubuntu 13.04 (raring), I had this problem.  It turns out that Ubuntu installs `_imaging.so` in a place that App Engine does not expect: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` instead of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL`.  So `_imaging.so` was not anywhere in `sys.path`.

Here are a couple ways around this:

**Put the PIL C modules somewhere already on the path:**

I noticed that `/path/to/google_appengine/lib/PIL-1.1.7` was in `sys.path`, but the directory did not exist in my installation.  So I created the directory and copied the .so files into it, and everything worked.  You would have to do this again, every time you updated the App Engine SDK, but at least it doesn't mess with the code you're developing.

**Manipulate sys.path in `main.py`:**

This code will check whether we're running the dev appserver, and if so, add the correct dir to the path.  Untested but it should work ;)

```
# Find _imaging.so and put its directory here.
# `locate _imaging.so` or `dpkg -L python-imaging`
PIL_PATH = '/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/'

PRODUCTION_MODE = not os.environ.get(
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 'Development').startswith('Development')

if not PRODUCTION_MODE:
    sys.path.insert(PIL_PATH)
```

I suppose that this might make more than just the PIL modules available to you, so that would introduce (yet more) differences between development and production.  Also, this technique involves modifying the source code of your app, which seems like a bad call if there's more than one person developing it.

---

*Note*:  If `import Image` fails, you might have forgotten to add the PIL library to your `app.yaml`.

```
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: "latest"
```

You might need to restart your `dev_appserver.py` after adding this library for the changes to be reflected in e.g. the interactive console.

Answer (score 0):

why the problem exists, is with PIL 1.1.6?  (only 1.1.7), 
Is that the version 1.1.6 does not use these libraries?

PIL 1.1.6 also uses its internal C library to speed things up.

For Windows you should use the precompiled packages. 
http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ offers X86 Windows binaries for 
1.1.7. You might run into a problem with 1.1.7 Windows binaries. The 
freetype C library references a debug CRT that is not available on all 
machines. You can easily patch the _imagingft.pyd file with a hex editor.

Comment: Could you help in detail how to fix the CRT reference in _imagingft.pyd file with hex editor ? Thanks

Comment: Check out the solutions here and see if it helps https://bitbucket.org/effbot/pil-117/issues/1/windows-build-of-_imagingft-module-fails. Please go through them carefully, and make backups before trying out the solutions

Answer (score 0):

I was completely missing the `_imaging.*` files in the `lib/site-packages/PIL` folder.

I downloaded the egg from here (the correct file depends on the platform):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0

renamed it from .egg to .zip`and copied all the files in the folder`PIL`that start with`_imaging`to the folder`lib/site-packages/PIL`.

.. Problem solved

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu, the following command helped me (thanks to [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149048/libjpeg-so-62-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)):

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
```