# Resize an image with python 2.4: The _imaging C module is not installed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-2.4

How to resize an image with python 2.4 version.I am trying t make it a thumbnail

I have downloaded thePIL librrary but am facing the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134966/problem-in-the-installed-pil.

Is there any other way to resize the image

```
from PIL import Image
import glob, os

size = 40, 40

for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
  file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
  im = Image.open(infile)
  im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
  im.save(file + ".thumbnail", "JPEG")
```

`raise ImportError("The _imaging C module is not installed")`

Comment: I had the same problem.  Clean install of **PIL 1.1.7** (currently latest) on top of clean install on **python 2.7.8** (currently latest) fixed the problem.  Make sure your python 2.7 is **32-bit**.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the same question : [PIL error: The _imaging C module is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074915/the-imaging-c-module-is-not-installed)

I hope that it will fix your problem !

Comment: I followed all the step in the link mentioned i still get the same error