# Python find rgb

Tags: python

I work with a Python and i want to know is it possible. That python makes picture of my screen and if this red box rgb value like: 12, 32 54. Then python runs one code.

http://www.upload.ee/image/2978408/omo.jpg

Plz help me;(

Comment: Please add more information to the question. Also please add the image to the question, don't provide an download link.

Comment: `Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x42 0x4d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `PIL` library.

Link: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("image.jpg")

pix = im.load()
print pix[x,y]
```

You will have to install `PIL` first.

Thanks [Kos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399317/kos) for the update...

Using `ImageGrab`, the code will look like:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab

# pixel color at x, y
print PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[x, y]
```

Note that `ImageGrab` only works in Windows.

Comment: ty but is it possible that it will use my active screen to find some rgb value. I dont want to make picture.

Comment: it says "image" is not defined

Comment: Have you installed PIL library?

Comment: >>> import PIL.ImageGrab

# pixel color at x, y
print PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[x, y]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    import PIL.ImageGrab
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 31, in <module>
    grabber = Image.core.grabscreen
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imaging C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed
>>>





 i got this error. Btw i have python 27. 64bit windows

Comment: Installing PIL may not be that straight forward... See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074915/the-imaging-c-module-is-not-installed

Comment: but can somebody please give me a link where i gone get pil for my python 26. Windows- 64 bit.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL EVERYBODY WORKS!